# Single instance of Jackson's ObjectMapper is not working

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I am using single instance of jackson's ObjectMapper with configuration Deserialization Feature fail on unknown properties is **false** in my Application. 
It's not working sometimes getting error 
Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id'): found multiple explicit names: [customeraddressid_v2_id, indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id], but also implicit accessor: [field com.indegene.bulkdata.dto.CustomerAddress#indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]

exception is coming only in dev env and not able to reproduce in my local system. This is sporadic issue.

```
mObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         mObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

 private String indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id;

@JsonGetter("indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id")
    public String getIndskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id() {
        return indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id;
    }
 @JsonSetter("customeraddressid_v2_id")
    public void setIndskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id(String indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id) {
        this.indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id = indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id;
    }
```

stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id'): found multiple explicit names: [customeraddressid_v2_id, indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id], but also implicit accessor: [field com.indegene.bulkdata.dto.CustomerAddress#indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder._explode(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:1062) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.explode(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:1041) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._renameProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:798) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:324) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._findCreatorsFromProperties(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:346) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:330) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:255) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:214) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:137) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:411) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:444) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:183) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:682) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:482) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4178) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3997) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3011) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar!/:2.9.4]
    at com.indegene.bulkdata.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.getCustomerAddress(ContactServiceImpl.java:490) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.indegene.bulkdata.service.impl.ContactServiceImpl.lambda$getCustomerAddressCompletableFuture$7(ContactServiceImpl.java:257) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

expected : I should not get error 
actual : sometimes it is throwing error

Comment: Can you please share the error/stacktrace of what you're getting as an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting this section of the error:

> found multiple **explicit** names: [customeraddressid_v2_id, indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id], but also implicit accessor: [field com.indegene.bulkdata.dto.CustomerAddress#indskr_indskr_customeraddress_v2id]

You'll notice there's *two* explicit declarations, so you probably have an `@JsonProperty` annotation elsewhere that is conflicting with the `@JsonSetter`.  Removing the extra annotation should resolve it.

Comment: same code is working fine but it's a flip-flop sometime exception

Comment: Maybe different input.